# What does boost::has_nothrow_constructor actually do for boost::variant?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

In the context of `boost::variant`, I understand that `boost::has_nothrow_copy` keeps copying from allocating the object being overwritten onto the heap incase the copy throws and the original needs to be recovered (though I'm a little surprised that it doesn't do a move).

However, I'm unclear as to the purpose of `boost::has_nothrow_constructor`.  Why does it need this? In the [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/variant/design.html#variant.design.never-empty) it states:

> ### Enabling Optimizations
>
> ...
>
> - If *any* bounded type is nothrow default-constructible (as indicated by `boost::has_nothrow_constructor`), the library guarantees `variant` will use only single storage and in-place construction for *every* bounded type in the `variant`. Note, however, that in the event of assignment failure, an unspecified nothrow default-constructible bounded type will be default-constructed in the left-hand side operand so as to preserve the never-empty guarantee.

This seems to indicate that without the specialization to `std::true_type`, this would result in using either multi storage or non-in-place construction.  What does that even mean?

NOTE: I actually found that [this pdf](https://scicomp.ethz.ch/public/manual/Boost/1.55.0/variant.pdf) was easier to read because it had more examples.

Comment: Move constructors and assignments didn't exist yet when these boost bits were first made

Comment: your question talks about `has_nothrow_constructor` generally but then suddenly you quote from docs for `boost::variant`. I suppose also when you write "Why does it need this?" then "it" refers to `variant` ?

Comment: " ... that boost::has_nothrow_copy keeps copying from allocating th..." similarly here it seems you assume some context but the context is unclear. `has_nothrow_copy` does not copy or move or allocate or overwrite anything, its just a type trait

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, yes, the context is in how it relates to `boost::variant`.  I tagged it as such, though I didn't explicitly state it in my question.  I've revised the question to make that link more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your quoted piece of Boost.Variant [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/variant/design.html#variant.design.never-empty).

Boost.Variant maintains a never-empty guarantee, meaning that no matter what happens during `boost::variant`'s lifetime, it is guaranteed to contain exactly one object of one of the types listed in its template parameters. This poses a problem with assignment to a `boost::variant` - what happens if assignment fails with an exception?

For example, let's consider the following piece of code:

```
std::string str("Some very long string");
boost::variant< int, std::string > var(10);
var = str;
```

Initially, `var` contains a value 10 of type `int`. Then it is assigned a value of type `std::string`, and for the sake of this example let's assume this assignment fails with an exception (e.g. `std::bad_alloc`).

Since the original stored value was not of type `std::string`, that value needs to be destroyed. `int` has trivial destructor, so destroying it is a no-op. But then the storage it occupied is reused by the newly constructed `std::string`, which is in this case copy-constructed from `str`. As we established above, this copy constructor throws, and there is no active value left in `var` - the string failed to construct and the previous `int` is already lost.

One solution could be to use a heap-allocated storage for constructing the string first, before destroying the currently stored value in the variant. If the construction succeeds, then the stored value is destroyed, and the variant stores a pointer to the newly constructed value internally. And that is what `boost::variant` does, with a few exceptions.

First, if the type of the value that is being assigned has a non-throwing copy constructor then this whole problem is non-existent - the copy construction is guaranteed not to fail, so it is safe to destroy the original value before the copy. This is detected by `boost::has_nothrow_copy`. This isn't our case in this example, as `std::string`'s copy constructor clearly can throw an exception.

Second, if *any* of the types that are listed in `boost::variant` template parameters has a non-throwing default constructor, as determined by `boost::has_nothrow_constructor`, then `boost::variant` can recover from a failed assignment by default-constructing a value of one of such types. Boost.Variant doesn't specify which of the types will be chosen if multiple types have a non-throwing default constructor, except that a special type `boost::blank` will be preferred, if listed. This optimization matches our case, as the default constructor of `int` is trivial and never throws. So the behavior of the assignment in our example will be as follows:

1. Destroy the currently stored value of type `int`.
2. Copy-construct a new value of type `std::string` in the internal storage of `var`.
3. If the copy constructor throws and exception, default-construct a value of type `int` in the internal storage and propagate the exception to the caller.

As a result, the value of `var` becomes an indeterminate value of type `int` (because the default constructor of `int` does not actually initialize it).

Comment: So what you're saying is to ensure that the never empty guarantee is adhered to, if there's an object with a `has_nothrow_copy` specialization, it'll do an inplace construction.  Otherwise, it'll attempt a default construction of an object that has a `has_nothrow_constructor` specialization (if one exists), and if none of those exist, it'll do a heap allocated temporary object copy of the original which is used to restore if there is an exception or is deleted if all goes well.  Is that correct?

Comment: > ...it'll do a heap allocated temporary object copy of the original -- No, it'll copy-construct the object that is being assigned on the heap. If that succeeds, the previously stored object is destroyed and `boost::variant` keeps the pointer to the object allocated on the heap, which (the object) it then exposes as its stored value. Also, you don't need to specialize `has_nothrow_copy` and `has_nothrow_constructor` if the compiler has support for intrinsics implementing these type traits.

Comment: > ...if there's an object with a `has_nothrow_copy` specialization, it'll do an inplace construction -- Correction - if the value that is being assigned has a non-throwing copy constructor.

Comment: That last correction, you are saying that because there may be intrinsics that the compiler has that make the `has_nothrow_copy` redundent?

Comment: If the compiler has intrinsics that `has_nothrow_copy` supports then `has_nothrow_copy` will just work as is and need not be specialized.